# document.getElementById("rock").remove(); not working

Tags: javascript

Have been following along with a rock paper scissors javascript game but the last part of the code is not working for me, the function rpsPage. When I click on one of the images I want them all to be removed but nothing is happening.  Cant figure out where I have gone wrong. Im not getting any error massage in the console and when I click on one of the images I expect them all to disappear from the page but instead they all remain and nothing seems to happen.

```js
function rpsGame(yourChoice){
    console.log(yourChoice);

    var humanChoice, botChoice;
    humanChoice = (yourChoice).id;

    botChoice = numToChoice(randonNum());
    console.log(botChoice);

    results = decideWinner(humanChoice,botChoice);
    console.log(results);

    message = finalMessage(results);
    console.log(message);

    rpsPage = (yourChoice.id, results, message);       
    

}

function randonNum(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
}

function numToChoice(number){
    return ['rock', 'paper', 'sissors'][number];

}
function decideWinner(yourChoice,computerChoice){
    var rspDatebase = {
        'rock':{'sissors':1, 'rock':0.5, 'paper':0},
        'paper':{'rock':1, 'paper':0.5, 'sissors':0},
         'sissors':{'paper':1,'sissors':0.5,'rock':0}    
    };

    var yourScore = rspDatebase[yourChoice][computerChoice];
    var computerScore = rspDatebase[computerChoice][yourChoice];

    return[yourScore,computerScore];

}

function finalMessage([yourScore,computerScore]){
    if (yourScore===0){
        return{'message':'You Lost', 'color':'red'};
    }else if (yourScore===0.5){
        return {'message':'You Tie', 'color':'yellow'};
    }else {
        return {'message':'You Won', 'color':'green'};
    };

}

function rpsPage(humanImageChoice, botImageChoice, finalmessage){
  
  document.getElementById("rock").remove();
  document.getElementById("sissors").remove();
  document.getElementById("paper").remove();
  
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class = "container-3">
      <div class = "flexbox-container-rps" id = "flexbox-rps-div">
        <img id="sissors" src = "sissors.jpg" style = "width:30%" alt = "sissors"  onclick = "rpsGame(this)" > 
        <img id="rock" src = "rock.jpg" style = "width:30%" alt = "sissors"  onclick = "rpsGame(this)" > 
        <img id="paper" src = "paper.jpg" style = "width:30%" alt = "sissors"  onclick = "rpsGame(this)" > 
        
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: as the below answer points out, you are not calling the function at all - rpsPage = (yourChoice.id, results, message); Since the call never takes place, the actions don't take place. if you are only now beginning to learn, a good idea is to put a simple console.log line in all your functions. that way, there is a small line in the console, telling you which function got called in what sequence. this is called 'caveman debugging'. It's old school but it works' especially for newcomers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the way you called the function, it must be called like this

```
rpsPage(yourChoice.id, results, message);
```

rather than

```
rpsPage = (yourChoice.id, results, message);
```

```js
function rpsGame(yourChoice) {
  console.log(yourChoice);

  var humanChoice, botChoice;
  humanChoice = (yourChoice).id;

  botChoice = numToChoice(randonNum());

  results = decideWinner(humanChoice, botChoice);

  message = finalMessage(results);

  rpsPage(yourChoice.id, results, message);
}

function randonNum() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}

function numToChoice(number) {
  return ['rock', 'paper', 'sissors'][number];

}

function decideWinner(yourChoice, computerChoice) {
  var rspDatebase = {
    'rock': {
      'sissors': 1,
      'rock': 0.5,
      'paper': 0
    },
    'paper': {
      'rock': 1,
      'paper': 0.5,
      'sissors': 0
    },
    'sissors': {
      'paper': 1,
      'sissors': 0.5,
      'rock': 0
    }
  };

  var yourScore = rspDatebase[yourChoice][computerChoice];
  var computerScore = rspDatebase[computerChoice][yourChoice];

  return [yourScore, computerScore];

}

function finalMessage([yourScore, computerScore]) {
  if (yourScore === 0) {
    return {
      'message': 'You Lost',
      'color': 'red'
    };
  } else if (yourScore === 0.5) {
    return {
      'message': 'You Tie',
      'color': 'yellow'
    };
  } else {
    return {
      'message': 'You Won',
      'color': 'green'
    };
  };

}

function rpsPage(humanImageChoice, botImageChoice, finalmessage) {
  
  document.getElementById("rock").remove();
  document.getElementById("sissors").remove();
  document.getElementById("paper").remove();

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container-3">
    <div class="flexbox-container-rps" id="flexbox-rps-div">
      <img id="sissors" src="sissors.jpg" style="width:30%" alt="sissors" onclick="rpsGame(this)">
      <img id="rock" src="rock.jpg" style="width:30%" alt="sissors" onclick="rpsGame(this)">
      <img id="paper" src="paper.jpg" style="width:30%" alt="sissors" onclick="rpsGame(this)">

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its beacuse you did not invoke your rpsPage function instead you assign an object value on it.

You should invoke it like this.

```
rpsPage(yourChoice.id, results, message);
```

and not assign a value like this.

```
rpsPage = (yourChoice.id, results, message);
```